# High availability cluster bandwidth bottleneck

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, haproxy

I want to setup a service with a lot of file transfer for thousands of users.
For now, my idea is to go with k8s + HAProxy with 3 masters (with VIP) and as
many slaves as needed.

So basically:

| Master0 | Master1 | Master2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Slave00 | Slave10 | Slave20 |
| Slave01 | Slave11 | Slave21 |
| Slave02 | Slave12 | Slave22 |
| ... | ... | ... |

HAProxy with VIP on the masters and replication between slave0X/1X/2X

The issue is that I'm afraid the masters throttle the bandwidth.
If I understand this correctly, the requests will do something like this:
`Client -> HAProxy -> masterX -> slaveXN`
So if there is `10` requests, the connection could be proxied to `3` masters
and `10` slaves. If we assume that all servers have `1Gb/s` eth, per request (on average),
the `slaves` will be able to receive/send `1Gb/s`, but the `masters`, only
`0.3Gb/s` (1Gb * 3 / 10) and `HAProxy` only `0.1Gb/s` (1Gb / 10).

Am I missing something or is there a better way to do this (DNS load
balancing?)?

Edit:
I did more research, the best I have for now is to have 10 slaves (1Gb/s) per master (10Gb/s), still replicated 3 times.
I could duplicate this setup with load balancing per user with authentication. I think this is possible with SSO redirection, if not, maybe just DNS load balancing.

Comment: What does the Kubernetes cluster use for networking and what kind of environment are the K8s nodes running in? Are you concerned about download (outbound) traffic only or is upload bandwidth a concern too? (If the former, the term you're looking for is "Direct Return" which means that inbound traffic flows through the load balancers but outbound traffic bypasses them.)

Comment: @Taavi For now I use fannel, Is there a better alternative for this use case?
It's mainly for file storage, so probably something like 70 % download, 30 % upload, DSR is something that I will probably setup, but I don't know if it will be enough for the long run.
Also, I thought of another way. I edited the original post to add it, if you could tell me what you think it would be amazing.